# In what way is this a wsgi middleware?

Tags: python, wsgi, django-middleware

I thought I understood the WSGI specification. So I'm looking at this Django module https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/middleware/locale.py and I just don't see how it's an implementation of a wsgi middleware as pep0333 explains it.

I was expecting a signature somewhere, such as

```
def __call__(self, environ, start_response)
```

as well as a small routine that would call another application and handle its returned value.

Could someone explain where's the server bit and where's the application in this middleware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django middleware is a little different then what you are thinking.  It sits inside of the django stack.  Through django middleware you have access to each step of the request and response a user makes/recieves.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/?from=olddocs

This just takes place within django.  WSGI handles processing the request and returning the response but django gives you hooks to modify it once it hits django.